# ad lds to create built in administrator account

Tags: active-directory, ldap, user-accounts

I created an Administrator account using AD LDS but cannot log in with it. I used ADSI tool to create the user:

```
CN=LDSAdmin,CN=Admin,O=MyCompany,C=CH
```

and  then added it to the built in group

```
CN=Administrators,CN=Roles,O=MyCompany,C=CH
```

and gave it a password by right-clicking on it in ADSI Edit and selecting "Reset Password". Now I cannot bind to AD LDS using Softerra LDAP Browser or any other LDAP tool, Softerra just hangs on logging in forever, other tools like LDAP Admin results in a "Invalid credentials" Error. I found descriptions on how to import an Administrator user using ldif but they didn't work. What am I missing here?
Cheers
Peter

Comment: I was able to create an Administrator using an ldifde import. When I export the user to the console I get: Writing out entries.
dn: CN=Administrators,CN=Roles,CN=Configuration,CN={53509D21-E875-451F-9CAF-E52B38D8F666}. So what are the credentials to log in now?

Comment: 1. Have you tried using the regular ADUC (ad.msc)? 2. Have you tried creating the user with Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the msDS-BindableObject class to LDSAdmin?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223505.aspx

Also check your other password attributes such as msDS-UserAccountDisabled.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/adam/directory-services-api-element-differences

AD LDS does not use a userAccountControl bitmask - that is just in AD DS.